# How can I set the logrus time to UTC

Tags: go, time-format

I am using Go with logrus, however I found the time field is always formatted in local time. How can I change the time to UTC time for logrus?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Time zone setting is not supported directly, but you may use a custom [`log.Formatter`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus#Formatter) in which you may "switch" to the time zone of your choice, UTC included.

A simple usage that uses the local time zone (not UTC) may look like this:

```
import (
    log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFormatter(&log.JSONFormatter{})
    log.Info("Testing")
}
```

Output (time is formatted using my `+01` local timezone):

```
{"level":"info","msg":"Testing","time":"2016-11-09T09:28:02+01:00"}
```

Now let's create a custom `log.Formatter` which switches to UTC:

```
type UTCFormatter struct {
    log.Formatter
}

func (u UTCFormatter) Format(e *log.Entry) ([]byte, error) {
    e.Time = e.Time.UTC()
    return u.Formatter.Format(e)
}

func main() {
    log.SetFormatter(UTCFormatter{&log.JSONFormatter{}})
    log.Info("Testing")
}
```

Output (time is formatted in UTC timezone):

```
{"level":"info","msg":"Testing","time":"2016-11-09T08:28:09Z"}
```

Comment: That's so clean. I love it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own implimentation of `logrus.Formatter`.

```
type Formatter interface {
    Format(*Entry) ([]byte, error)
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus/issues/293)